# How to automatically set a `deploymentLabel` in Spring Cloud Data Flow for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using the following Deployer Property for SCDF to give my Stream Source a label.

`deployer.my-source.kubernetes.deploymentLabels=importer-source:myimporter`

The thing is that I have to manually write this down for every redeployment I want to do with this stream.
I was seeing a Skipper Configuration that has all the properties that are visible in the SCDF Streams Deployer Properties. But I was not able to find the `deploymentLabel` property in there.
I think its some kind of custom property?
As you can see it is not listed in here: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/streams/deployment-properties/

But it does work so I wonder how I can set it in skipper since it's no "official" or documented property.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Kubernetes deployer as the corresponding property `deploymentLabels` was not added to the Kubernetes deployer properties when the support to have this property in the K8s app deployer was [made](https://github.com/chrisjs/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/commit/1478f95db84e12c1c6b2bcad03948f8c086a45ca).

I have created an issue to track this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues/344
Thanks for reporting this!